# drawing a graph like we draw it in math ... using javascript

Tags: javascript, math, graph

i don't want to draw a chart ! i want exactly a graph with some nodes and some edges . i want to draw it ( some lines and some circles ) . is there a good library for javascript to do that kind of thing ?
i've read similiar questions but all of them were about charts and some given data.
and please consider that i want a free library and i don't need algorithms like BFS . i just want to draw something like this : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use d3.js: http://d3js.org/

Here is an example close to what you want to do: http://christophermanning.org/projects/building-cubic-hamiltonian-graphs-from-lcf-notation/